# What does the "me" in the rel attribute mean?

Tags: xhtml, attributes

I know the 'nofollow' means to Search Engines "Don't follow this link" (or at least, don't give SEO juice to that link), but what does the "me" mean?

I often see it paired up with "nofollow".

What is it used for? Where should it be used? What are the advantages?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"me" means that this link leads to another of your profiles on the internet. Its for semantic purposes only.

i see that you use wordpress, so to see a full implementation go to the links page and add a new one. Near the bottom you'll see a link relationship section. The textbox at the top shows what the rel will look like on the link element once you save. This way you can explore how relationships influence the rel attribute.

Heres some further reading on this microformat: [XFN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML_Friends_Network)

Answer (score 1):

http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-me

has all explanations (including 30sec YouTube videos)